# Delimiters in splitting string in python

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I know this question has been asked a few times, but what I'm asking is not how to do it, but which delimiter should be used.

So I have a very long string and I want to split it into words. The result is not what I wanted, so I thought to add another delimiter.

The problem is there are words like `vs.` and `U.S.` in the string. If I use `.` as a delimiter, I will get `vs` but `U.S.` becomes `U` and `S`. This is not what I wanted.

Another example, there are words `brainf*ck` `*7` `F***ing` `x*x+y*y` `works*` `f*k` in the string. If I use `*` as a delimiter, the result will be very messy (`brainf*ck` becomes `brainf` and `ck`, `F***ing` becomes `F` and `ing`, and so on)

`'` delimiter have the same problem; (`don't` `'starting` `out'` `what's` `do's` `dont's`)

`-` `=` `+` `(` `)` also have some minor problem but I can handle those delimiters. The problem is with `.` `*` `'`.

Does anyone have any idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: IMHO this is a very difficult problem. You probably need to categorize the type of possibilities that can happen and see if you can extract a pattern. if you are able to categorize then you have a concrete problem at hand otherwise it is x-y problem.

Comment: Maybe you'd better use regular expressions for this. (re module)

Comment: Why not `spaces` be used for splitting words ?

Comment: Maybe escaping characters could be useful. For instance, `*` can have many meanings: in `brainf*ck` it's a character, whereas in `x*y` it is an operator. In the first word, its nature is the same as the other elements, but in the second, it is different since `x` and `y` are variables. Maybe `brainf\*ck` could be something acceptable.

Comment: You might also consider classifying your strings. For instance, `brainf*ck` is a word, but `x*y` is an expression. Each category would have its own behaviour toward separators.

Comment: @Nishant yes, thank you for your opinion. I agree with you and this problem is something I came up with just because I'm curious. Thanks again :)

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Thank you, I have used it, and the result is what I can call as "better than nothing" :)

Comment: @Sarathsp I have used `spaces` to split the string. The result is good enough. But I'm just curious on how to solve this problem. Unfortunately, `whitespace` is not enough

Comment: @Rightleg I don't think it is possible to classify each word, since the string is very very long. The problem I have shown is just the one I found. Who knows what other problem occured inside the string.

Comment: @user3429874 Actually I was thinking of declaring **manually** the type of the string... But if your goal is to scrape some content, for instance, it's not really possible.

Comment: @user3429874 a `delimiter`  followed by `space or tab` should be a decent approach

Answer (score 0):

What about using re:

```
import re
text = 'U.S. vs. brainf*ck *7 F***ing x*x+y*y works* f*k'
get = re.split('\s', text)

# ['U.S.', 'vs.', 'brainf*ck', '*7', 'F***ing', 'x*x+y*y', 'works*', 'f*k']

#Example
print(get[0]) # U.S.
print(get[1]) # vs.
```